# Gensim saving corpus to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, gensim

I am using `gensim`, but when I try to save to a `s3` location with `Mmcorpus.serialize` it sends an error:

```
corpora.MmCorpus.serialize('s3://my_bucket/corpus.mm', corpus)                                                                                           
2016-01-12 15:55:41,957 : INFO : storing corpus in Matrix Market format to s3://my_bucket/corpus.mm
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-513a98b2dfd4> in <module>()
----> 1 corpora.MmCorpus.serialize('s3://my_bucket/corpus.mm', corpus)

/home/nanounanue/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gensim/corpora/indexedcorpus.py in serialize(serializer, fname, corpus, id2word, index_fname, progress_cnt, labels, metadata)
     92                 offsets = serializer.save_corpus(fname, corpus, id2word, labels=labels, metadata=metadata)
     93             else:
---> 94                 offsets = serializer.save_corpus(fname, corpus, id2word, metadata=metadata)
     95 
     96         if offsets is None:

/home/nanounanue/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gensim/corpora/mmcorpus.py in save_corpus(fname, corpus, id2word, progress_cnt, metadata)
     47         logger.info("storing corpus in Matrix Market format to %s" % fname)
     48         num_terms = len(id2word) if id2word is not None else None
---> 49         return matutils.MmWriter.write_corpus(fname, corpus, num_terms=num_terms, index=True, progress_cnt=progress_cnt, metadata=metadata)
     50 
     51 # endclass MmCorpus

/home/nanounanue/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gensim/matutils.py in write_corpus(fname, corpus, progress_cnt, index, num_terms, metadata)
    484         is allowed to be larger than the available RAM.
    485         """
--> 486         mw = MmWriter(fname)
    487 
    488         # write empty headers to the file (with enough space to be overwritten later)

/home/nanounanue/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gensim/matutils.py in __init__(self, fname)
    434         if fname.endswith(".gz") or fname.endswith('.bz2'):
    435             raise NotImplementedError("compressed output not supported with MmWriter")
--> 436         self.fout = utils.smart_open(self.fname, 'wb+') # open for both reading and writing
    437         self.headers_written = False
    438 

/home/nanounanue/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py in smart_open(uri, mode, **kw)
    132                 return S3OpenWrite(key, **kw)
    133             else:
--> 134                 raise NotImplementedError("file mode %s not supported for %r scheme", mode, parsed_uri.scheme)
    135 
    136         elif parsed_uri.scheme in ("hdfs", ):

NotImplementedError: ('file mode %s not supported for %r scheme', 'wb+', 's3')
```

*NOTE*: `s3://my_bucket` exists (with another name), and `corpus` is the same from the tutorial of `gensim`.

Which is the correct way of do it? I want to achive the following: store the corpus (or a model, like LDA) in S3 and getting it from S3 and run it again.